# How do I insert a pause (delay) in my Selenium command line (selenium-side-runner) test?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pause

I'm using selenium-side-runner v 3.11.0 and trying to insert a pause (delay) in my test so that after a click, there is some time before the next action.  I have tried this

```
, {
      "id": "ec6aa5e8-c72b-4bf5-8061-a7a360370923",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "click",
      "target": "linkText=Log in",
      "targets": [
        ["linkText=Log in", "linkText"],
        ["css=.login-link", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//a[contains(text(),'Log in')]", "xpath:link"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='header-bottom-right']/span/a", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//a[contains(@href, 'https://www.reddit.com/login')]", "xpath:href"],
        ["xpath=//div[3]/span/a", "xpath:position"],
        ["xpath=//a[contains(.,'Log in')]", "xpath:innerText"]
      ],
      "value": ""
    }, {
"id": "fbf35ed7-1a28-4540-a93d-3cb8ba0e012a",
"comment": "",
"command": "pause",
"target": "",
"targets": [],
"value": "35000"
},
```

But I'm noticing the pause isn't activated at all.  Even though in the above I've put a long time (35 seconds) to wait, the test skips straight to the next command.  I'm using the chromedriver on Mac Mojave.  What is the proper way to insert a pause command?  I'm running the test on the command line like so

```
PATH=/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/starter_project/selenium/dev/:$PATH selenium-side-runner --headless -c "browserName=chrome" /tmp/81a312ad-8fe1-4fb0-b93a-0dc186c3c585.side
```

Comment: instead of `value` as `35000` can you try with `target` as `35000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the delay value should go in `target`

```
{
"id": "fbf35ed7-1a28-4540-a93d-3cb8ba0e012a",
"comment": "",
"command": "pause",
"target": "35000",
"targets": [],
"value": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pause target takes in milliseconds, so convert your seconds to milliseconds and add it in **Target** field

```
{
      "id": "ec6aa5e8-c72b-4bf5-8061-a7a360370923",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "click",
      "target": "linkText=Log in",
      "targets": [
        ["linkText=Log in", "linkText"],
        ["css=.login-link", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//a[contains(text(),'Log in')]", "xpath:link"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='header-bottom-right']/span/a", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//a[contains(@href, 'https://www.reddit.com/login')]", "xpath:href"],
        ["xpath=//div[3]/span/a", "xpath:position"],
        ["xpath=//a[contains(.,'Log in')]", "xpath:innerText"]
      ],
      "value": ""
    }, {
"id": "fbf35ed7-1a28-4540-a93d-3cb8ba0e012a",
"comment": "",
"command": "pause",
"target": 35000, #for 35 seconds
"targets": [],
"value": ""
},
```